# PHP - get a KEY of a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-key

I have an array called   `$plugins` that looks something like this :

```
Array
(
    [path/to/file.php] => Array
        (
            [Name] => somevalue_a
            [TextDomain] => somevalue_b
            [value_c] => somevalue_c
            [value_d] => somevalue_d
            ...
            ...
            ..

        )
    [path/to/file2.php] => Array
        (
            [Name] => somevalue_a
            [TextDomain] => somevalue_b
            [value_c] => somevalue_c
            [value_d] => somevalue_d
            ...
            ...
            ..
        )
)
```

Now, I am having trouble to get the KEY name (which is path)of each array element ..

```
function get_plugin_data(){

    foreach ($plugins as $plugin => $data) {
    $plugin_data = $plugins[$plugin];

    // Start simple DEBUG
    echo '</br>===============================</br>' ;
    echo '</br><b>Plugin Name : </b>'. $data[Name]; .'</br>' ;
    echo '</br><b>Plugin Path : </b>'. key($plugins)   .'</br>' ; // <-- Problem here
    echo '</br>TextDomain set  : '. $data[TextDomain] .'</br>' ;
    echo '</br>===============================</br>' ;
    // End DEBUG
    }
}
```

When using `key($plugins)` it gives me always the same value (first one).
When using `key($data)` it is giving me the FIRST LETTER only.. (??)

How can I get the this key of each nested array ?

Comment: just return `$plugin`, not `key($plugin)`. $plugin should already be the key.

Comment: @kennypu my god .. Too sleepless. you are right . Add as an answer and I will accept .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just return `$plugin`, not `key($plugin)`. `$plugin` should already be the key.

to elaborate, when you use the syntax:

`foreach ($plugins as $plugin => $data)`

it is setting `$plugin` to the key, and `$data` to it's value.

Comment: ok, Got it . But then why key($data) is giving me ONE (first) letter ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen that's an interesting question, I would imagine it should error, as $plugin in this case is a string, not an array. Even if strings were treated as an array, it should return '0' not the first character of the string. I have no clue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` loop indicates that the path are available as `$plugin`. Use that

```
   foreach ($plugins as $plugin => $data) {
                      // ^ This represents the key of the array item
    $plugin_data = $plugins[$plugin];

    // Start simple DEBUG
    echo '</br>===============================</br>' ;
    echo '</br><b>Plugin Name : </b>'. $data[Name]; .'</br>' ;
    echo '</br><b>Plugin Path : </b>'. $plugin .'</br>' ; // <-- Problem here
    echo '</br>TextDomain set  : '. $data[TextDomain] .'</br>' ;
    echo '</br>===============================</br>' ;
    // End DEBUG
   }
```

Comment: thanks, I got to realize from kennzpu´s answer a simple fact (that I need more sleep :-) ) .. Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Check this modification to your code, it works now.

```
<?php
    $plugins = Array
    (
        'array1' => Array
            (
                'name' => 'somevalue_a',
                'TextDomain' => 'somevalue_b',
                'value_c' => 'somevalue_c',
                'value_d' => 'somevalue_d'

            ),
        'array2' => Array
            (
                'name' => 'somevalue_a',
                'TextDomain' => 'somevalue_b',
                'value_c' => 'somevalue_c',
                'value_d' => 'somevalue_d'

            )
    );

    function get_plugin_data($plugins){

        foreach ($plugins as $plugin => $data) {
        $plugin_data = $plugins[$plugin];

        // Start simple DEBUG
        echo '</br>===============================</br>' ;
        echo '</br><b>Plugin Name : </b>'. $data['name'] .'</br>' ;
        echo '</br><b>Plugin Path : </b>'. key($plugins)   .'</br>' ; // <-- Problem here
        echo '</br>TextDomain set  : '. $data['TextDomain'] .'</br>' ;
        echo '</br>===============================</br>' ;
        // End DEBUG
        }
    }
    get_plugin_data($plugins);
    //print_r($plugins);
?>
```